# How Do I add a Custom Legend to a Plot, R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So, I'm trying to add a custom legend to my R graph.  I'm trying to add this legend to explain the lines I have in my plot:

[image: Here's the plot's link]

So, my goal is to have a legend saying that the blue lines represent the Standard Deviation.

Here is my code so far:

```
kernal.dens <- ggplot(daily.ret2.df, aes(x=Daily,color = year))+
  geom_density(data = filter(daily.ret2.df, year != 2019),adjust=2, size=1, show.legend = T)+
  geom_density(data = daily.ret2.12,adjust=2, size=1.75, show.legend = T)+
  geom_segment(lty=1,aes(x = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily),xend = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily),
                         yend = 5,y = 0),color = "blue",size = .5)+
  geom_segment(lty=1,aes(x = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*2,xend = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*2,
                         yend = 5,y = 0),color = "blue",size = .5)+
  geom_segment(lty=1,aes(x = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*-1,xend = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*-1,
                         yend = 5,y = 0),color = "blue",size = .5)+
  geom_segment(lty=1,aes(x = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*-2,xend = sd(daily.ret2.12$Daily)*-2,
                         yend = 5,y = 0),color = "blue",size = .5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c( "black", '#3A8026', "#7F8931", "#C4933D","#C47422", "#C45608", 
                              "#B12F08", "#9E0808", "#80262D"),
                     labels = c(' Last 12 Months ',' 2011   ',' 2012   ',' 2013   ',' 2014   ',' 2015   ',' 2016   ',
                                ' 2017   ',' 2018   '))+
 legendGrob(labels = 'Sd',do.lines = T,nrow = 1,ncol = 1)+
  grid.legend(draw = T)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-.1,.1,.05), 
                     labels = paste0(seq(-.1,.1,.05)*100,'%'))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50,5))+
  labs(x='\nReturn\n',y='Density\n',title=paste0(asset, ' Daily Return Densities\n'))+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=.5,size=44-max(0,nchar(asset)-6),face='bold'),
        axis.text=element_text(size=20,color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=28,color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text=element_text(size=18,color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

When I put this in I get this error:

```
Error: Don't know how to add legendGrob(labels = "Sd", do.lines = T, nrow = 1, ncol = 1) to a plot
```

I think the error is that R doesn't have data to know what each item in the legend corresponds to in the plot.

Whenever I see an example of adding a custom plot, there is already an old plot to replace, but for my situation I want a plot that doesn't already exist.

Thank you for your time regardless of your capabilites of helping me.  I would also love any advice on adding legends in R and related topics to further understand them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a geom\_segment show a legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552125/how-to-get-a-geom-segment-show-a-legend)

Comment: Not super familiar with grobs but I think this `legendGrob` can't be added to the plot with `+`. See the example in `?legendGrob` using `grid.draw()`